# get distinct values in LINQ query

Tags: linq

I wrote this query:

```
            var queryDetails = DbContext.ProductEventNotificationDetails.Where(p 
                 =>p.ProductEventNotifications_Id == ID).ToList().Select(r => new
                        {
                            r.Id,
                            NotificationMethod = 
                               r.NotificationContact.NotificationMethod.Name

                        });
```

So, i need to get only distinct values based on NotificationMethod value. If I use distinct() at the end, it schedules according to Id. Can you please let me know how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

```
var queryDetails = DbContext.ProductEventNotificationDetails
    .GroupBy(x => x.NotificationMethod)
    .Select(group => group.Key);
```